# Is it possible for ELK APM to trace for apache ignite calls?

Tags: elasticsearch, ignite, elastic-apm

Is It even possible for ELK APM to trace for apache ignite calls?

Used below value but no use , i am getting the JMX and Http traces but can't see any traces which is getting triggered by org.apache.ignite

used parameter -Delastic.apm.application_packages=com.xxx.app,org.apache.ignite

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

As of now elastic is not enable with apache ignite. So it can't be able to trace the ignite request.